# How to constrain type as abstract type member in trait?

Tags: scala, types, traits

I would like to define the following trait with an abstract type:

```
trait C {
  type M[_]

  def doSomething(m: M[T]): M[T] = ???
  def somethingElse: M[T] = ???
}
```

I'd like to constrain my higher type `M` to have a `scalaz.Monad[M]` instance. One solution would be to change my code like:

```
abstract class C[M: Monad] { ... }
```

but I would like M to be an abstract type member. Is this possible in Scala?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to require a `Monad[M]` instance, just... require it:

```
trait C {
  type M[_]
  /*implicit if you like*/ def m: Monad[M]
  ...
}
```

Implementing classes will unfortunately have to specify m, if only as `val m = implicitly`; the only way around that is the `abstract class` approach you mention.

Comment: It appears to be the only option. I would have liked to avoid the override